# In multiple different DB enviroment with EF core, need to access Connection state

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

in a project with different databases (SQL Server, Oracle etc) for EF Core 3.1, I have a base class from which a top level class for each database is derived from. The main problem is I can't access the connection state for the underlying database.

The point is not to rewrite the basic code for each database type - just the differences.

The basic code is similar to this. I have removed the extra parts for clarity.

```
public class CNAdapterBase<Provider, ConnectStrBuilderType, CommandType> 
{
    private readonly Provider _dbProvider;

    private string _connectionString;
    private ConnectStrBuilderType _connectStr;
    private CommandType _command;
    ....

}

public class CNMSSql : CNAdapterBase<SqlConnection, SqlConnectionStringBuilder,SqlCommand>
{
     ...
}
```

Similar code to above for Oracle etc.

Any working suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All the ADO.NET Connection objects should derive from [System.Data.Common.DbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=net-5.0), and the Command objects derive from [System.Data.Common.DbCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand?view=net-5.0).

So you can have instances of these abstract base classes in a (non-generic) base class to your "adapter".